# Search for a specific RegEx

Tags: egrep

I have a command who make an output like that :

```
[size][tabulation][path]
```

I want to exclude all path that have more than one level

keep :

```
/a
```

exclude :

```
/a/b
```

or :

```
/a/b/c[...]
```

But i didn't found any RegEx who can do that. I think about something like

```
[space][path][space]
```

but there not any space in the output, just one tabulation per line and that's all

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
egrep '\s/[^/]+$'
```

**Explanation

```
\s          # any kind of spaces
/           # a slash
[^/]+       # character class, 1 or more any character that is not a slash
$           # end of line
```